firebase firestore database add function does nothing
i have a problem while adding data to firestore. i have an empty database named mydb.
when i try to add data to firestore .it does absolue nothing. the code i am using from the official site rnfirebaseio is below.
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{
      
          firestore()
          .collection('Users')
          .add({
            name: 'Ada Lovelace',
            age: 30,
          })
          .then(() => {
            console.log('User added!');
          }).catch((e)=>{console.log("fail",e)})
          .finally(() => console.log("did anything happen"));
        }}>
          <Text>click me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

and the output at console is nothing.
I am able to add data to storage from this page so it is not about the configuration i guess.
any help would be appreciated.
